# CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey - Create a permanent key container that accessing the certificate

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptoapi, pfx

How do i create a persistent key container using `cryptoAPI` from a PFX self signed certificate?

I am able to access the private key in the PFX via `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` call but how do i import the private and public key pair in to a key container? This key container should be permanently present in the USER key store after completing the import process.

Looking forward for suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to import the certificate, and the key pair with respect of [PFXImportCertStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Another way could be interesting for the understanding. You can save the key pair which you get with respect of the `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` in any new key container. Then you can import the certificate only (without the private key) and at the end you should set the container with the private key as the property of the certificate ([CertSetCertificateContextProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID`).

In the practice one use always [PFXImportCertStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but I recommend you to write a test program which you [CertEnumCertificateContextProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376049%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and look at the properties which will be saved together with the certificate in the certificate store, but which are **not** a part of the certificate.

Comment: @Oleg- Thanks. I managed to export the PFX successfully, after setting the CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO. But when i import the same PFX using the wizard, it creates a Key container name of its own and not the one which i previously set when exported? Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: @Raj: If you import PFX new container will be created (typically new GUID will be used) and the certificate property will be set so, that it points to the new container. The name on the container is not important. It is not the part of the certificate or its private key. So the name of the key container will be not exported in the PFX.

Comment: @Oleg, So if i want to retain the original  key container name when i am going to import, progrmatically,(In my case, Key container name will the cert subject name), Will setting the structure CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO before importing will retain the original key container name? Thanks

Comment: @Raj: Sorry for late answer. I didn't played much with `PFXImportCertStore` and all this was some years before :-). Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741519/saving-restoring-certs-with-ms-cryptoapi-invalidates-attached-private-key/5741893#5741893) which definitely work, but the exact behavior with the key container you should better test yourself.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for the reply. I am going to test this and will update the answer. regards

Comment: @Oleg: Though i accomplished my required task for my project, i tried to do the test suggested by you by trying to store the private key in a new key container with CryptExportKey (PRIVATEKEYBLOB). It didn't work for me as the CA who issued the certificate has marked the key as non-exportable. I believe that it would have worked if otherwise.

Comment: @Raj: Sorry, but I don't understand why you try to use `CryptExportKey` if you has already `PFX` file? If I understand you correct you want to **import** the data. You can work with `PFX` file mostly like with an existing certificate store. Moreover I don't understand which CA you mean in your last comment. Is the `PFX` file contains the CA certificate or is it contain a child certificate with the corresponding private key plus the CA certificate without the private key? Could you describes your situation more exactly.

Comment: I refer to a third party CA who  is approved by the country with where we have our client. yes, the PFX is having a CA cert+child cert with the pvt key. In your answer, you have asked me to try to export the pvt key from the certificate. Thats what i tried. But if you have referred to exporting the certificate in to a new cert, then i have obviously misunderstood comment.