# Saving/Restoring certs with MS CryptoAPI invalidates attached private key

Tags: windows, winapi, cryptography, cryptoapi, mscapi

I've written a program which is supposed to save and restore a users certificates using the windows Crypto API.  I was under the impression that it was working fine but now a user has complained that the private key that was attached to the certificate is invalid after the cert has been restored.

I was saving the certificates using:

```
HCERTSTORE hCertStore =
    CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_PHYSICAL_W,
    0,
    NULL,
    CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER |
    CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG |
    CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG |
    CERT_STORE_UPDATE_KEYID_FLAG,
    (PVOID) storeName.c_str());
```

And then later:

```
if (!CertSaveStore(hCertStore,
    0,
    CERT_STORE_SAVE_AS_STORE,
    CERT_STORE_SAVE_TO_FILENAME,
    (PVOID) saveFile.c_str(),
    0))
```

I understand that the CERT_STORE_SAVE_AS_STORE flag should mean that the entire cert should get serialized including the private key.  Although I note that MSDN says:

> "The CERT_KEY_CONTEXT_PROP_ID property
>   and the related
>   CERT_KEY_PROV_HANDLE_PROP_ID and
>   CERT_KEY_SPEC_PROP_ID values are not
>   saved to a serialized store."

..which I confess, I don't really understand.

When I restore the cert I use CertFindCertificateInStore() to see if the cert is already present and only if it isn't I do:

```
bOK = CertAddCertificateContextToStore(
    hDestinationStore,
    pCertContext,
    CERT_STORE_ADD_USE_EXISTING,
    NULL);
```

To add the certificate back...  So my question is, why might the private key not be preserved?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use wrong CryptoAPI. You should use [PFXExportCertStoreEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387313%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [PFXImportCertStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387314%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

**UPDATED**: The functions are very common. You can not export certificates from the SmartCard of course or other non-exportable certificates. The BLOG in the function is nothing more as the contain of the PFX file. For example the import of the certificate from PFX file should do the following:

1. Open the PFX file and read full contain in the memory. You can use of course the file mapping instead.
2. Optionally you can use `PFXIsPFXBlob` function to verify that the file has really contain which corresponds to the PFX file.
3. You use `PFXImportCertStore` to open the BLOB (the PFX) as the source certificate store.
4. You use `CertOpenStore` or some other function to open the destination certificate store where you want save the certificates from the PFX file.
5. You use `CertEnumCertificatesInStore` to enumerate certificates from the source certificate store (PFX) and for all certificate use `CertAddCertificateContextToStore` to add certificate from the source certificate store to the destination certificate store. The certificates having private key will be imported with the private key.
6. You use `CertCloseStore` to close both opened stores.

Comment: Hmm, looks promising, will this function work for all types of cert/cert store?

Comment: @Benj: I updated my answer with the information from one my old working program. I hope it will be enough for you to write your own program. The export is very simple, but the import is a little more complex so I described the import more detailed.

Comment: This seems to work brilliantly.  I've got my program merrily saving/restoring all the certs including the private keys now..  Thanks so much!