# CryptoAPI CryptImportKey fails with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER but imports the key

Tags: delphi, winapi, cryptography, cryptoapi, pkcs#12

I am trying to import private RSA key from a PKCS#12 file. I am using OpenSSL to parse the P12 and then I am trying to use CryptImportKey to import the key into the CSP ("Standard" enhanced RSA provider).

Ï create the blob exactly same way as I get it when I do export the key from CSP with CryptExportKey.

Lastly I do not want to use any session encryption as I am only parsing encrypted file and storing it into CSP.
If I use

```
publickeystruc.aiKeyAlg := CALG_RSA_KEYX;
```

and

```
if not CryptImportKey(tmpprovider,addr(privkey),dwBlobLen,0,flags,hPubKey) then 
  errorCode := GetLastError;
```

(so 0 for the key parameter) then the function fails and I get ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER error. But the key gets imported and is fully working (I tried to sign with it and I was able to export it if it was marked exportable).

Variables are declared like this:

```
 hpubkey:PHCRYPTKEY;
 privkey:privkeyblob;
```

where

```
  HCRYPTKEY   = ULONG;
  PHCRYPTKEY  = ^HCRYPTKEY;
```

the rest are integers and cardinals...

Problem solved, it was a really stupid bug. I forget to dereference the last parameter when I was zeroing it in the beggining of the function, so instead of

```
hPubKey^:=0;
```

I had

```
hPubKey := 0;
```

Thanks TLama for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I would suspect the note about `hPubKey`: *some cryptographic service providers may modify this parameter as a result of the operation* and if you are passing there a constant it can't be modified, so I would try to define it as a variable with type `HCRYPTKEY`, set it to 0 and pass it to the function. But it's just a guess.

Comment: The function prototype from JEDI library looks like this `function CryptImportKey(hProv: HCRYPTPROV; pbData: LPBYTE; dwDataLen: DWORD; hPubKey: HCRYPTKEY; dwFlags: DWORD; var phKey: HCRYPTKEY): BOOL; stdcall;`. So I would try to declare the last parameter this way `hPubKey: HCRYPTKEY;`.

Comment: I am using Jedi and I think I have it declared as you said.

Comment: If you are using JEDI's [`JwaWinCrypt.pas`](http://jedi-apilib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jedi-apilib/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/JwaWinCrypt.pas?revision=1113&view=markup) then if you would use variable declaration `hpubkey:PHCRYPTKEY;` as you have in the question, you would get `Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical` compiler error, so include your real variable declarations.

Comment: I am using wcrypt2.pas and it has it decalred as   PHCRYPTKEY  = ^HCRYPTKEY; and   HCRYPTKEY   = ULONG; I had to make my own declaration of the key blob though but it should be according to MSDN

Comment: `HCRYPTKEY = ULONG_PTR` but anyway, try to review your function header and structures with the JEDI's [`JwaWinCrypt.pas`](http://jedi-apilib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jedi-apilib/jwapi/trunk/Win32API/JwaWinCrypt.pas?revision=1113&view=markup).

Comment: I will definetly do that. The interesting thing is that all the other functions from the Jedi wcrypt2 work and this one seems to work too only I get that error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10414/discussion-between-tlama-and-radek-hladik)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you try to import private RSA key from a PKCS#12 file. It seems to me that you should use [PFXImportCertStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this. The schema of importing you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741893/315935). If you need just get the private key and save it somewhere else you can replace the step with the usage of `CertAddCertificateContextToStore` to `CertGetCertificateContextProperty`. The call of `PFXImportCertStore` create the key container *automatically*. Using `CertGetCertificateContextProperty` with `CERT_KEY_PROV_INFO_PROP_ID` will get you the key container as `pwszContainerName` filed of [CRYPT_KEY_PROV_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, thats actually one option too. I was briefly looking into this way but I choose the other one because I already have PKCS#12 parsing, etc for importining into PKCS#11 tokens. I also have certificate import into CSP and CSP key generation and export. So only thing missing to have "complete" set would be importing a key. But if this way will fail or I will find it more difficult I am ready to test the PFXImportCertStore. As far as I get it it will create new memory store and I will need to copy its content into i.e. MY store.